# Initializing RxJava stream with a value

Tags: rx-java

I have the following RxJava stream:

```
val msgToSendPublisher = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(MessageToSend())

msgToSendPublisher
    .flatMap { _ ->
        App.context.repository.getMessageToSend().toObservable()
    }
    .doOnNext {
        msgToSendPublisher.onNext(it)
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe()
```

The flatMap parameter is an underscore and when msgToSendPublisher is called, it passes "it". Currently I am not using this parameter. I need to modify my code so that it does use it but I need to make it so that when the stream is initially called, it provides an initial value. The modified code would look something like this:

```
msgToSendPublisher
    .flatMap { id ->
        App.context.repository.getMessageToSend(id).toObservable()
    }
    .map {id ->
        msgToSendPublisher.onNext(id)
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe()
```

So before the stream starts, I would want id set to "12346". What do I have to do to set the initial value?

Comment: What is the problem? You already had a solution in the top example. Is there a problem changing just `_` to `id` while keeping the other code parts?

Comment: Changing _ to id isn't the issue. Setting id to an initial value is.

Comment: Why is `createDefault` not working for you? Where should that initial id come from?